# Django orm on apple m1

Tags: mysql, django, docker, django-orm, apple-m1

I'm trying to get concrete number of records in django model with 1m+ records through `python manage.py shell` using docker on **apple m1** machine. Query:

```
Model.objects.all()[:200000]
```

But shell fails with message `Killed`. On machine with linux everything works fine. Any idea?

Comment: You are simply OOM

Comment: You should monitor your memory on both machines and show the output at x records selected.

Comment: Yeah. I've viewed docker settings. By default 2 gb memory available for docker. I just increased memory usage and it works. Thx all